# How to Convert Every Letter in the Alphabet To an Integer - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, alphabet

I am trying to convert every letter in the alphabet to an integer like this

```
A = 1;
B = 2;
...
Z = 26;
```

I went through some forum questions but none of them worked well. Is there a way of doing this without Arrays?

Comment: what did the forum questions suggest and which parts didn't work?

Comment: What is an alphabet for you?

Comment: Try something, if that fails think about the problem, the failure, search the docs and try again with the new knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for lowercase letters you need to subtract 96 from its value. Like this:

```
int a = 'a' - 96; // 1
```

for uppercase ones subtract 64. Like this:

```
int A = 'A' - 64;// 1
```

This will work for any letter of English alphabet

Comment: What about `ç`, `Š` or `á`?

Comment: @Cyrille they don't belong to the English alphabet

Comment: Hence @Sulthan's question, "What is an alphabet for you?" Not everyone's mother tongue is English.

Comment: Heck, even the word "Alphabet" originates from the Greek alphabet (Alpha, Beta, ...)

Comment: but the questioner is obviously meaning the English alphabet, cause he gives example starting from A and B and ending with Z

Comment: Here's a list of proper English words with accents in them: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_with_diacritics

Comment: @Cyrille but there are NO such letters in English alphabet